# Show records falling day to day per group between months

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot, days

I have two tables:

`Ticket` table:

```
sale_date, center_id, ticket_id
```

`Center` table:

```
center name, center_id
```

I need help on how to make the results look like the one attached image:

[image]

I have tried to run the script, re arranging does not give me luck.

```
declare @salefrom      datetime
declare @saleto        datetime

select @salefrom = '2015-10-01 00:00:00'
select @saleto   = '2015-10-31 23:59:59'

SELECT
    DATEPART(MM, t.Sale_Date) [MONTH], 
    DATEPART(DD, t.Sale_Date) [DAY], 
    c.Center_name [centers], 
    COUNT(ticket_id) AS [Tickets]
FROM 
    Ticket t 
INNER JOIN 
    Center c ON c.center_id = t.center_id
WHERE
    t.Sale_Date BETWEEN @salefrom AND @saleto 
    AND t.status <> 1 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(MM, t.Sale_Date), DATEPART(DD, t.Sale_Date), c.Center_name
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(MM, t.Sale_Date), DATEPART(DD, t.Sale_Date), c.Center_name
```

Thanks,
lemi

[image: Results i am getting from running the above script]

Comment: You need grouped counting and pivot, but please provide sample data. Best would be a working [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: You can not span or merge column as month row you want. But get in all columns.  Only option I though is union the results with three section

Comment: can you post dome data.

Comment: Hi, I was able to produce the result that i need using pivot, by first creating temp table, then from there run the pivot script. But the issue is, how to convert the month row to column, like from horizontal to vertical  without affecting day to day results. any help will be appreciated.